# Sumar resultados de N cantidad de bases de datos y mostrar en DataGridView

Tags: c#, net

Obtengo los datos de conexión N  base de datos que estan almacenados en una tabla, obteniendo los datos de conexion procedo a recorrer y ejecutar consultas, los resultados de cada consulta necesito sumarlos para obtener un total final.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                string dirIP;
                string puerto;
                string baseDatos;

                baseDatos = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value);
                dirIP = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3].Value);
                puerto = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[4].Value);

                String errorMsg;
                OdbcConnection con = Connect("usuario", "pas", puerto, dirIP , baseDatos, out errorMsg);
                if (con != null)
                {
                    String cadena = "SELECT " + 
                    "(SELECT count(*) FROM sysobjects) [objetos]," +
                    "(SELECT COUNT(*) from sysusers where uid > 16383) [grupos]";
                    OdbcDataAdapter adp1 = new OdbcDataAdapter(cadena, con);

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    adp1.Fill(dt);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        // MOSTRAR LOS RESULTADOS EN ESTE DATAGRIDVIEW
                        dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
                        dataGridView2.Refresh();
                    }

                }
        }
```

Comment: Si en un loop de dataGridView1 asignas el DataSource de dataGridView2, en cada iteracion vas a pisar los datos anteriores. Deberias realizar un Merge() de los datatable y por fuera del foreach asignas el Datasource de dataGridView2

Answer (score 0):

Podrias aplicar el `Merge()` del datatable para unir las diferentes respuestas

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("objetos", typeof(System.String)));
dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("grupos", typeof(System.String)));

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    string baseDatos = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value);
    string dirIP = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3].Value);
    string puerto = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[4].Value);

    string errorMsg;
    OdbcConnection con = Connect("usuario", "pas", puerto, dirIP , baseDatos, out errorMsg);
    if (con == null)
        continue;

    string cadena = @"SELECT  
                    (SELECT count(*) FROM sysobjects) [objetos],
                    (SELECT COUNT(*) from sysusers where uid > 16383) [grupos]";
    OdbcDataAdapter adp1 = new OdbcDataAdapter(cadena, con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adp1.Fill(dt);

    dt1.Merge(dt);
}

dataGridView2.DataSource = dt1;
dataGridView2.Refresh();
```

[DataTable.Merge Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.merge?view=netframework-4.7.2)